# Text is failing to wrap

Tags: html, css

On the following form, longer descriptions are bleeding off of the form in DESKTOP mode, into one long line. This is true on the Preview, tho the preview of the phone device wraps.
[LINK](https://listriff.com/guest)
How can we fix this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vs7aZ.jpg)

Comment: In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your **relevant code** in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the **question itself**. External sites may be malicious, flagged by filter systems, or removed at a later stage (rendering your question useless). It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have tried so far to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Looks as if `white-space: nowrap;` is in the CSS for that line...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's this CSS rule being applied:

```
.form-sub-label-container {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

To avoid that, either delete it (if you can), or overwrite it with the following rule in your custom CSS:

```
.form-sub-label-container {
    white-space: normal;
}
```

Comment: At 31k rep you *really* should know that it's not a good idea to answer questions which are off-topic (e.g. this one has nothing even remotely attempting to be a MCVE in the question).